# Android Buttons not stretching to width of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-library

I'm using a bootstrap library for android which can be found [here](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap). Ive imported the library into my application but the problem im having is that the buttons **do not span the entire screen width**.
I've tried placing the buttons side by side and using `android:layout_weight="1"` but the button just moves to the left and does not stretch. I've even tried using `android:layout_width="match_parent"` but that increases the buttons height as well.

[image: This is how my layout looks with the library]

this is what happens if i set `android:layout_width="0dip"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` (for ok/cancel) and `android:layout_width="match_parent"`(for check button)

[image]

XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:bootstrapbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20sp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="318dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Pin To Email id."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter Your Email Id Below"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapEditText
    android:id="@+id/et_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="abc@example.com"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    bootstrapbutton:be_roundedCorners="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="15sp" >

    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
        android:id="@+id/OK"
        style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="OK"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_left="fa-envelope"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_roundedCorners="true"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_size="medium"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_type="default" />

    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="CANCEL"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_left="fa-times"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_roundedCorners="true"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_size="medium"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_type="default" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15sp"

    android:text="Got your Pin?Enter it below."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapEditText
    android:id="@+id/et_pin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="XXXX"
    android:inputType="number"
    bootstrapbutton:be_roundedCorners="true" />

<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
    android:id="@+id/b_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Check"
    bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_left="fa-check"
    bootstrapbutton:bb_roundedCorners="true"
    bootstrapbutton:bb_size="medium"
    bootstrapbutton:bb_type="default" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: whicb utton you need to be streched ? ok/cancel or check ?

Comment: @androidKiller both of them actually.. i want 'ok/cancel' to be side by side (ie of the same size and fill the width) and 'check' to fill the width of the screen.

Comment: Try to use dp for padding and margin instead of sp which is mainly use for text size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use width as `0dip` instead of `wrap_content` if you use weight property.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="15sp" 
    android:weightSum="2">
    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
        android:id="@+id/OK"
        style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="OK"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_left="fa-envelope"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_roundedCorners="true"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_size="medium"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_type="default" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="CANCEL"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_left="fa-times"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_roundedCorners="true"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_size="medium"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_type="default"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

And for single button, just use width as "match_parent"

```
<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
    android:id="@+id/b_check"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Check"
    bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_left="fa-check"
    bootstrapbutton:bb_roundedCorners="true"
    bootstrapbutton:bb_size="medium"
    bootstrapbutton:bb_type="default" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it didn't work..ive added a screenshot above of what happens when i added your code

Comment: @MysticMagic i think its a problem with the library itself. i know your code works for perfectly for a normal button so im gonna mark this as the correct answer.